# Storing Image In Database Without JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Good day stackers,

I'm working on a web project in which we recreate a social media site similar to snapchat. I'm using my webcam to take pictures using JS, and I'm writing the picture to a var called img as follows:

```
var img    = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

We are required to use PDO in PHP to access the database. Alternatively we can use AJAX, but JQuery is strictly forbidden. My question is, how can I store the DataURL inside my database? All the tutorials online use JQuery.

Update:

I followed the steps as suggested below, but when I hit the snap button, it still only takes the picture, but no URL or nothing.

```
function sendimagetourl(image)
        {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
                {
                    alert( this.resoponseText);
                }
            }
            xhtp.open("GET", "saveimage.php?url="+image, true);
            xhttp.send();
        }
        //Stream Video
        if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia)
        {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true}).then(function(stream) {
            video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            video.play();
            });
        }
        //Snap Photo
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var video = document.getElementById('video');

        document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 800, 600);var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); sendimagetourl(image);});
```

So it appears I was a bit of a fool. There were two minor typos, and it seems like the data sent is invisible in the url. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: you may use simple javascript ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript ajax

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    alert( this.responseText);
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "saveimage.php?url="+url, true);
xhttp.send();
```

Comment: Do I use $_GET['url'] to retrieve the data in PHP then?

Comment: yes you can use $_GET['url']   , as it is a get request

Comment: I'll let you know in about 10 minutes. This is similar to some of the posts I read so I'm sure it will, I'm just struggling a tad to implement it, but I'll get it running soon, then I'll let you know.

Comment: I followed the steps but it's not working. Please have a look at my question on top where I posted details on my new problem.

Comment: are you using any js library to click the image?

Comment: No, no libraries are allowed. I was looking for a physical change in the URL, but I'm assuming it's invisible with XMLHttp requests?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`XMLHttpRequest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch), `Blob`, [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) to `POST` `data URI` to `php`. See also [Using files from web applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications)

```
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("POST", "/path/to/server", true);
  request.onload = function() {
    // do stuff
  }
  var data = new FormData();
  data.append("image", new Blob([img], {type:"image/png"}), "filename");
  request.send(data);
```